# A variant of subset sum problem with two different sets

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization

The original version of subset sum problem is that, given a set of integers and an integer s, does any non-empty subset sum to s ?

I have a variant of this problem but on two different sets. Given two set of integers $a$ and $b$. Both of them have N elements. Also given two numbers $s_a$ and $s_b$. Find a binary vector $x \in \{0,1\}^N$ such that $a^Tx=s_a$ (I) and $b^Tx=s_b$ (II)

To solve this problem, my approach is to relate it to any existing NP problems such as subset sum, Knapsack, IP problem, etc. but so far I have not found any connections. Subset sum, both single and multiple version, can satisfy either (I) or (II), but not both. Knapsack is similar. Although I can play a trick by adding two constraints to force $b^Tx<s_b$ and $b^Tx>s_b$, that solution is not quite natural...

Is there any problems which is close to this problem ? 'close' here means that I can reduce one to the other or vice versa.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. What are you asking? btw i think the problem you proposed is just as difficult as original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this problem is NP complete as well.

If you could solve this problem, you could also solve the problem with all $b_i = 0$ and $s_b = 0$, solving Knapsack. (This is the only direction you have to prove.)

And on the other hand, obviously you can check any solution polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks. I was too focused on proving this problem as an instance of another problem in order to solve it, so I forgot the other way round. However, knowing that the problem is harder than Knapsack still cannot help me to solve this problem heuristically...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving , though in this case, you may have to modify the weights a bit.